# Как реализовать данный запрос

Tags: mysql, laravel, mvc, запрос

На въюхе у меня должно быть два цикла: один выводит все категории, второй, который находится внутри первого, выводит все бренды данной категории. Пример:

```
//model
        $categories = DB::table('products')
                ->join('categories', 'products.c_id', '=', 'categories.id')
                ->select('categories.name as cat')
                ->groupBy('categories.name')
                ->get();
        $brands = DB::table('products')
                ->join('categories', 'products.c_id', '=', 'categories.id')
                ->join('brands', 'products.b_id', '=', 'brands.id')
                ->select('brands.name as brand')
                ->where('categories.id', '=', '1')<-- об этом речь пойдёт ниже
                ->groupBy('brands.name')
                ->get();

//view

                @foreach($categories as $category)
                <li><a>{{ $category->cat }}</a>
                    <ul class="sort-section">
                        <li><a href="#"><strong>All CPUs</strong></a></li>
                        @foreach($brands as $brand)
                        <li><a href="#">{{ $brand->brand }}</a></li>
                        @endforeach
                    </ul>
                </li>
                @endforeach
```

Проблема заключается в выделенной мною строчкой в модели. Я "выбираю" записи, где `id` категории = 1(проверял или всё остальное работает), когда на самом деле мне нужно выбирать `id` поточной категории(поточной на въюхе). Другими словами, если бы я это делал по-простому и по-неправильному, то я бы второй запрос осуществлял бы внутри первого `foreach` на въюхе. Каким образом можно решить данный вопрос?

Comment: Непойму, что мешает тебе у модели категории сделать метод getBrands() там вызывать свой заппрос только строчку поменять на `where('categories.id', '=', $this->id)`

Comment: @Orange_shadow каким образом я его буду вызывать с въюхи, для каждой категории?

Comment: Создай модель категорию и в ней реализуй функционал.  и будет у тебя собственно так `$categories =  App\Category::all();` а во вью `foreach($categoreis as $category){ ... foreach($category->getBrends() as $brend) {} ... }`, если у тебя категории как-то должны отсеиваться создай scopeSearch($query) и отсей ненужное

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Работает следующим образом:

// Controller

```
$getAll = DB::table('categories')
                    ->leftJoin('products', 'products.c_id', '=', 'categories.id')
                    ->leftJoin('brands', 'brands.id', '=', 'products.b_id')
                    ->groupBy('brands.name')
                    ->groupBy('categories.name')
                    ->get([
                        'categories.id as id',
                        'categories.name as cat',
                        'brands.name as brand'
                    ]);

        $categories = [];
        if (count($getAll)) {
            foreach ($getAll as $single) {
                if (!isset($categories[$single->id])) {
                    $categories[$single->id] = new \StdClass();
                }
                $categories[$single->id]->cat = $single->cat;
                $categories[$single->id]->brands[] = $single->brand;
            }
        }
```

//View

```
@foreach($categories as $category)
 <li><a>{{ $category->cat}}</a>
   <ul class="sort-section">
     <li><a href="#"><strong>All {{$category->cat}}</strong></a></li>
     @foreach($category->brands as $brand)
        <li><a href="#">{{ $brand }}</a></li>
     @endforeach
   </ul>
 </li>
@endforeach
```

Comment: т.е. у вас в контроллере написана вот такая полотня ? Это как бы не очень верно, теперь представьте вы залезете  сюда через месяца 4, и о боже что я тут написал, несомненно вы вспомните что выбираете категории в них бренды, но .... все было бы гораздо прозрачнее если бы тут было в контроллере всего 2 строки, перая выбрать категории, вторая передача их во вьюху, во вьюхе бы использовали метод бы getBrends().

Comment: @Orange_shadow я не смог в полной мере реализовать такой вариант, поэтому довольствуюсь тем что есть

Answer (score 0):

Для такой ситуации в Laravel существует hasManyThrough

Добавояем метод в модель категории, если правильно построена бд и не надо явно указывать по каким полям то так:

```
class Category extends Model {

    public function brands()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Brand', 'App\Product');
    }

}
```

Теперь в контролере можно вызвать $category->brands